# SQL Sum values of a give node for a given time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like

```
ServicePointID          EndTime              Energy Usage
1                2004-01-01 06:30:00.00          6075Kwh
2                2004-01-01 06:30:00.00         14000Kwh
3                2004-01-01 06:30:00.00          1250Kwh
4                2004-01-01 06:30:00.00            40Kwh
1                2004-01-01 07:00:00.00          7106Kwh
2                2004-01-01 07:00:00.00         10000Kwh
3                2004-01-01 07:00:00.00         11000Kwh
4                2004-01-01 07:00:00.00         12000Kwh
```

...

I am trying to sum all of the values for a given timestamp, 
kinda like

```
     EndTime              Energy Usage Total
2004-01-01 06:30:00.00          21365Kwh
2004-01-01 07:00:00.00          40106Kwh
```

Comment: Simple `SELECT EndTime, SUM(Energy usage) AS total FROM tab GROUP BY EndTime`

Comment: Is this literally being stored as `'6075Kwh'`?  As a `VARCHAR`?  If it is, that complicates your query quite a bit..

Comment: Don't store 'kwh'

Comment: it does not store the 'kwh'.  It is being stored as a varchar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select endtime, sum(energyusage) as Energy_Usage_Total
from table_name
group by endtime;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not storing Kwh but if you really need to, here's a query to help you with the idea. Take note that this is in SQL Server and i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. Hope this helps

```
SELECT  [EndTime] ,
        CAST(SUM(CAST(LEFT([Energy Usage], LEN([Energy Usage]) - 3) AS 
        NUMERIC)) AS VARCHAR(max)) + 'Kwh'
FROM    @table
GROUP BY [EndTime];
```